# Spring boot generic exception handler for SOAP proxy client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a wrapper class that calls a web-service via proxy client jar. I have found myself writing the same try\catch for the different methods for this client. I saw there is a way to create generic exception handlers for Controller classes, but this isn't that. Is there a way I can have spring or some other method of writing the try\catch once and reusing it for each of the client calls?

Example:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class proxyClient{

  public int method a(){
     try { 
        return client.a()
     }
     catch(Exception1 e){}
     catch(Exception2 e){}
     return null;
  }
  public int method b(){
     try { 
        return client.b()
     }
     catch(Exception1 e){}
     catch(Exception2 e){}
     return null;
  } 
  public int method c(){
     try { 
        return client.c()
     }
     catch(Exception1 e){}
     catch(Exception2 e){}
     return null;
  }
}
```

I'd love to be able to have something handle those exceptions for me so I have less code duplication, but I only want it done for this class.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal structured code with classes and instances around? You provided two methods with a same signature.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but regarding exception clutter, I would just use `throws` keywords everywhere and handle exceptions at top-level: https://www.javatpoint.com/throws-keyword-and-difference-between-throw-and-throws

Comment: @tmarwen updated. Just assume that "client" is my service proxy that makes the web service call. So my class exposes an a, b, and c method which then invokes the proxy client and returns the results. It's overly simplified, more logic lives in there, but for the example I just wanted to show the catch redundancy

Comment: @Kilves - I had thought about throwing exceptions and putting logic to handle the exceptions up a level, but I saw there were some spring tricks for generic handlers at controller levels and was wondering if there was any other slick way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

The most common and fancy way of doing that, is to use *AOP* (*Aspect Oriented Programming*) as exception handling is a cross-cutting concern which this paradigm is aimed to enhance.

You can create an aspect *Advice* to handle exceptions thrown by any service (assuming that there is even others) under your package (here referred to as *some.package.service* as you have not provide the full class content):

```java
package some.package.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlerPointcut {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* some.package.service.*.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void handleException(Exception ex) {
        // your common exception management code
    }

}
```

Make sure to annotate your main configuration (or spring boot application) class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to enale `@Aspect` classes discovery.

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions are [checked exceptions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-checked-unchecked-exceptions#checked), then you must either handle them with `try-catch` as you are doing now or simply re-throw the exception by adding the `throws ExceptionClassName` to the method.

If you choose to re-throw, then whatever component is using `ProxyClient` will either need to `try-catch` or re-throw.

With that said, you can make use of [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and make a utility method to call the method:

```
@Service
public class ProxyClient {

    public Integer method a() {
        return doAction(client::b);
    }

    public Integer method b() {
        return doAction(client::b);
    }

    public Integer method c() {
        return doAction(client::c);
    }

    public Integer doAction(Supplier<Integer> action) {
        try {
            return action.get();
        } catch (Exception1 e) {
            // ...
        } catch (Exception2 e) {
            // ...
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You don't appear to be doing anything from your example other than returning `null` if any exception is thrown. So I'm not sure what you were looking for with Spring.